# didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo for two images

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have two image views named `obsPic1` and `obsPic2`

They receive an image from picker/camera. This works fine for one image but any more and the images are the same. How do I do this for more than one image?  Ive tried accessing the buttons sender tag but get undeclared identifier error, ive also tried using `if` statements.  Whats the correct way to do this?

```
- (IBAction)addObsPhotoBtnPresssed:(id)sender {
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        LogCmd();
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
        [self.editController presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
        //iPad
    }
    else {
        if (self.pop) {
            [self.pop dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        }
        UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imagePickerController.delegate = self;
        imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;
        self.pop=[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePickerController];
        [self.pop presentPopoverFromRect:((UIButton *)sender).bounds inView:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

    }
}


- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    self.obsPic1.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.obsPic1.image = image;
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    NSString *path = [ICUtils pathForDocument:@"obsPic.png"];
    [imageData writeToFile:path atomically:NO];


    UIImage *image2 = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    self.obsPic2.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.obsPic2.image = image2;
    NSData *imageData2 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    NSString *path2 = [ICUtils pathForDocument:@"obsPic2.png"];
    [imageData2 writeToFile:path2 atomically:NO];


}
```

Comment: I don't see any reference to `obsPic2` in the above code, where are you adding an image to `obsPic2`?

Comment: Code adjusted, missed that off the copy & paste

Answer (score 1):

Both your `image` and `image2` reference the same image:

`[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]`

Are you perhaps looking to reference the Edited and Original images:

```
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
```

and

```
    UIImage *image2 = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

or vice versa?  If OTOH you're trying to allow for multiple image picking look into [ELCImagePickerController](https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController)

Comment: Ah ok thanks for that, makes sense why im getting same image now and no both references are edited images.  thanks for the link, although Its not really going to be suitable for me in this case. I Still need to find way of getting different images into each image view

Comment: If you want to put a different image in each view you'll have to have them pick twice to get two different images.  Just do an `if` to check if your `obsPic1` already has an image in it and if so populate `obsPic2`.  If you found the answer helpful plz to vote it up even if its not answering you 100% :)